# Gradle build fails after upgrading to Android plugin 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I upgraded to Android Studio 3.0. The build works fine on my OS X dev machine (in both the IDE and command line), but fails on our Linux builder (command line).

Our project has an `app` module that depends on a `common` (Java) module and a `lib` (C++) module. The `lib` module is built with CMake and uses SWIG to generate the Java API for the C++ code.

On the builder, the `:app:javaPreCompileRelease` task is executed before `:lib:generateJsonModelRelease`, which initiates the CMake build. This results in compile errors in the `app` module, because the Java classes have not been generated in the `lib` CMake build.

Is there a way to enforce this dependency? I'm not sure why the behavior is different between platforms/versions.

---

working build output

`:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:clean UP-TO-DATE
:lib:externalNativeBuildCleanDebug
:lib:externalNativeBuildCleanRelease
:lib:clean UP-TO-DATE
:common:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:lib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:lib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:lib:checkReleaseManifest
:lib:processReleaseManifest
:common:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:common:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:common:checkReleaseManifest
:common:processReleaseManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:lib:compileReleaseAidl
:common:compileReleaseAidl
:app:compileReleaseAidl
:lib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:common:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:app:prepareLintJar
:app:generateReleaseResValues
:app:generateReleaseResources
:lib:compileReleaseRenderscript
:lib:generateReleaseResValues
:lib:generateReleaseResources
:lib:packageReleaseResources
:common:compileReleaseRenderscript
:common:generateReleaseResValues
:common:generateReleaseResources
:common:packageReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
:app:processReleaseManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease
:lib:platformAttrExtractor
:common:platformAttrExtractor
:lib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:lib:prepareLintJar
:lib:javaPreCompileRelease
:lib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:common:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:common:prepareLintJar
:common:javaPreCompileRelease
:common:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:app:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:mergeReleaseShaders
:app:compileReleaseShaders
:app:generateReleaseAssets
:lib:mergeReleaseShaders
:lib:compileReleaseShaders
:lib:generateReleaseAssets
:lib:mergeReleaseAssets
:common:mergeReleaseShaders
:common:compileReleaseShaders
:common:generateReleaseAssets
:common:mergeReleaseAssets
:app:mergeReleaseAssets
:app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:lib:generateJsonModelRelease`

... CMake build starts; build completes successfully

---

Failing build output

`:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:clean UP-TO-DATE
:lib:externalNativeBuildCleanDebug
:lib:externalNativeBuildCleanRelease
:lib:clean UP-TO-DATE
:common:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:lib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:lib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:lib:checkReleaseManifest
:lib:processReleaseManifest
:common:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:common:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:common:checkReleaseManifest
:common:processReleaseManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:lib:compileReleaseAidl
:common:compileReleaseAidl
:app:compileReleaseAidl
:lib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:common:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:app:prepareLintJar
:app:generateReleaseResValues
:app:generateReleaseResources
:lib:compileReleaseRenderscript
:lib:generateReleaseResValues
:lib:generateReleaseResources
:lib:packageReleaseResources
:common:compileReleaseRenderscript
:common:generateReleaseResValues
:common:generateReleaseResources
:common:packageReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
:app:processReleaseManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease
:lib:platformAttrExtractor
:common:platformAttrExtractor
:common:processReleaseResources
:lib:processReleaseResources
:app:processReleaseResources
:app:generateReleaseSources
:lib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:lib:prepareLintJar
:lib:generateReleaseSources
:lib:javaPreCompileRelease
:lib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:lib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:lib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
:common:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:common:prepareLintJar
:common:generateReleaseSources
:common:javaPreCompileRelease
:common:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:common:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:common:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
:app:javaPreCompileRelease`

... compile errors about missing Java classes that should be generated in CMake build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I didn't find a way to get the build to run normally, I was able to run it in two steps:

```
./gradlew lib:assembleRelease
./gradlew assembleRelease
```